# Read a plain text file and get line 3 of text after underscore

Tags: php, file, fopen

I have a text file containing text like this...

```
test test_0000
test test test_1234
test test apple_4567
test test orange_8910
```

How do I use fopen to open the file, read line number 3 and print the value after "_" in php?

I have tried like this:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("text.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        ?>
        <div id="application"><center>
            <div><?php echo explode('_', $buffer)[1]; ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

This displays all lines after "_"

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Comment: ^ Add this to your question and show your work! Just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30150784/edit) your question

Comment: I can't see the problem here, aren't you able to count until 3 or what is actually the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just read the file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then get the position of the first `_` with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and then you can take the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) from this position until the end of the line.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $line = 3;
    echo substr($lines[$line-1], strpos($lines[$line-1], "_") + 1); 

?>
```

output:

```
4567
```

Comment: Wow!!... Thats quick and excellent response.. Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: One more issue, It is showing an error if no text is in the text file. Any solutions please.

Comment: @Beney Just put a check if your line which you want exists, e.g. `if(isset($lines[$line-1])) echo ...`